# Investigating why a pointer turns bad (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, pointers, visual-studio-debugging, watch

A piece of C++ code I am looking into in VS 2008 has a bad pointer. The pointer is initialized properly and has very few lines of code referencing it. I put a watch on this pointer while debugging.

When a certain method is called, the value of the pointer suddenly changes from  **0x05fe0040 ""**  to **0x00000000 Bad Ptr**  (in the Watch window of VS2008). I can't seen to figure out why this is happening. There are no operations on the pointer between the lines of code where it loses its value.

How do I investigate this further? What are some possible reasons why this pointer has turned bad?

I am new to C++ programming and am using VS2008 for the first time, so please explain anything you think is pertinent.

Comment: post the code, even if it seems right to you.

Comment: You are probably overwriting portion of your stack. Or maybe your pointer goes out of scope. Post code for more...

Comment: Perhaps if you could share some code we would be able to help...

Comment: You can debug with gdb putting a watch point to the memory region. Thus you can see where it get's corrupted and by which variable.

Comment: The value of the pointer inside the function call, outside it? It could be if you have the pointer in a watchlist and step into a function then as the pointer is no longer in scope, it cannot be evaluated by the watch windows. There are many possibilities really, code example plus a more accurate description of exactly what you are doing will help.

Comment: In fact, you should look more into the operations on those pointers declared/allocated around that pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the value is not changed by any code manipulating the variable, it must be accessed by a [stray/dangled pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) or by a [buffer/array overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).

[Use a memory breakpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/350dyxd0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) on the pointer variable, this way the debugger will show you quickly what code is corrupting it.

Comment: I used the memory breakpoint you mentioned above. Turns out, a separate process was calling the destructor deallocating the memory assigned to the pointer. Thanks a lot, this is a very neat function!

Answer (score 2):

You may have accessed beyond an array index or some invalid memory (e.g. uninitialized pointer) somewhere else and overridden the value of the pointer variable.